# What to type in for int32 pixelFormat in Swift?

Tags: swift, parameters, int32, pixelformat

I'd like to use the function CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue.

The documentation tells me to use the following possible values for "pixelFormat":
(The parameter needs to be an Int32)

```
The desired Core Media pixel format of the output frame data. The value must be one of the following:
'BGRA': Packed Little Endian ARGB8888
'l10r': Packed Little Endian ARGB2101010
'420v': 2-plane "video" range YCbCr 4:2:0
'420f': 2-plane "full" range YCbCr 4:2:0
```

If I type in for example 'BGRA', then Xcode tells me that this is an invalid argument. What shall do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **C** language you can specify a multi-character constant which results in an `int32` value.  **Swift** doesn't provide this natively.  You can just pass the equivalent constant.

For `'BGRA'` you need to pass `0x42475241`.  `0x42` is the ASCII value for `B`, `0x47` is the ASCII value for `G`, etc.

I verified this by creating this function in `C`:

```
int32_t convertBGRA() {
    int32_t i = 'BGRA';

    return i;
}
```

and calling it from Swift:

```
print(String(format: "%x", convertBGRA()))  // output: "42475241"
```

---

Here are all of the values:

```
let pixelFormat_BGRA = 0x42475241
let pixelFormat_l10r = 0x6c313072
let pixelFormat_420v = 0x34323076
let pixelFormat_420f = 0x34323066
```

---

Here is an extension to `Int32` that initializes the value from a string of 4 characters.

```
extension Int32 {
    init?(char4: String) {
        var result: UInt32 = 0

        let scalars = char4.unicodeScalars

        if scalars.count != 4 {
            return nil
        } else {
            for s in scalars {
                let value = s.value
                if value > 255 {
                    return nil
                }
                result = result << 8 + value
            }
            self = Int32(bitPattern: result)
        }
    }
}
```

For an input of `'BGRA'` you'd use:

```
Int32(char4: "BGRA")!
```